# Passing my stream to a worker thread node.js

Tags: node.js, multithreading, node-streams, worker-thread

I have to implement this custom method of Multer storage in order to encrypt file before saving it.

I have implemented my function encrypt, which will comunicate with a worker thread.

```
import { Worker, isMainThread } from 'worker_threads'
import path from 'path'
export const encrypt = ({ destination, filename, file, password }) =>
  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    if (isMainThread) {
      const workerPath = path.resolve(__dirname, './encryptWorker.js')
      const worker = new Worker(workerPath, {
        workerData: {
          destination,
          file,
          filename,
          password
        },
      })

      worker.on('message', resolve)
      worker.on('error', reject)
      worker.on('exit', (code) => {
        if (code !== 0) {
          reject(new Error(`Worker stopped with exit code ${code}`))
        }
      })
    }
  })
```

and the `file` params which is getting into the function contains basics information (name, length) plus the `file.stream` which is essential for its transformation.

The issue is coming when I am passing it to the Worker Thread: since it uses the [structured clone algorithm](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Structured_clone_algorithm) to clone it and passing as worker data, it happens that this `file.stream` is getting `undefined` into the worker thread. 
I tried also to pass directly the `file.stream` params but, for the same reason above i am receiving `DataCloneError` issue, because I am passing a FileStream.

Any suggestion about how to solve this issue? I tried several approach to bypass it, one of them is writing the stream into an `ArrayBuffer` and then read it using another stream in the Worker Thread, but to be honest I would know if there is a better approach to resolve it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you cannot explicitly use the multer library with worker threads.

But you can work around it. My approach is to let multer write in the main thread to a temporary directory, then perform my heavy work on a different thread.

Before performing it, I move the files from the temp directory to my desired location with `fs.rename` inside the worker thread.